# What am i doing in this postgreSQL configuration (Tapestry)

Tags: hibernate, tapestry

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
 <session-factory>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/thetable</property>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres123</property>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

**ERROR**

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /blah/balahhh. Reason:

    Exception constructing service 'ValueEncoderSource': Error invoking service contribution method org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateModule.contributeValueEncoderSource(MappedConfiguration, boolean, HibernateSessionSource, Session, TypeCoercer, PropertyAccess, LoggerSource): Exception constructing service 'HibernateSessionSource': Error invoking constructor public org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.HibernateSessionSourceImpl(org.slf4j.Logger,java.util.List): Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
```

It worked before when i use a "hsqldb". But now i get the shown error.

Comment: please include the full stack trace, don't post it as an answer, edit your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this project was I have defined pom.xml to download different dependency libraries. But the log4j has been downloaded twice from two different repositories (tapestry & tika). The versions were different. So what i did was check the maven tree and added exclusions for the place where it downloads the older slf4j.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>          
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

First impression is that you are missing your driver class from the classpath. This might be caused by a number of factors including maven, your deployment etc..

In your AppModule, in your `bind` method (create if you don't have) try the following:

```
public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        System.out.println("driver found in classpath");
    }
    catch(Throwable e)
    {
        System.out.println("driver not found in classpath");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ...
}
```